# How to Call Method from main?

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I am attempting to modify the point values using my MoveUp method. However I am having trouble instantiating the class and its new values in the main method. I declared `Point x1 = new Point();` then `x1.moveUp();`, but moveUp(); creates an error that the method is not applicable for the arguments.

```
   public class Point {
        private int xcoord = 6;
        private int ycoord;



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point x1 = new Point();
        x1.moveUp();
        System.out.print(x1);

    }


        public Point ()
        {
            xcoord = 0;
            ycoord = 0;

        }


        public Point (int x, int y)
        {
            x = 9;
            y = 8; 
        }


        public int getX ()
        {
            return xcoord;
        }


        public int getY ()
        {
            return ycoord;
        }


        public void moveUp(int amount) 
        {
            amount = xcoord + 1;
        }


        public void moveDown(int amount) 
        {
            amount = ycoord - 2;


        }


        public void moveRight(int amount)
        {
            amount = xcoord + 1;

        }


        public void moveLeft(int amount) 
        {
            amount = xcoord - 1;


        }
    }
```

Comment: `x1.moveUp();`, method decleration: `void moveUp(int amount) `

Comment: it has a parameter of type `int` so pass an int argument..it will work fine

Comment: First of all, your method `moveUp` does nothing but modifies the argument. The newly assigned value will never be used.Second: your method has an argument, but you call it without an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Your `move*` methods have incorrect logic.

If you wish to pass the amount by which to move the `Point`, as implied by the parameter name, the logic should be updating `xcoord` or `ycoord`, not the local variable `amount`.

For example, in order to move up you should add `amount` to `ycoord` :

```
    public void moveUp(int amount) 
    {
        ycoord += amount;
    }
```

Then you would call the method with :

```
x1.moveUp(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the method declaration

```
public void moveUp(int amount)
```

it requires a int parameter, so your code should be something like

```
x1.moveUp (50);  // or some other input from your program
```

Also fix the logic error in you `move*` methods

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, moveUp method takes 'amount' as an argument. But you are calling it as

x1.moveUp();

i.e. without argument. That's the reason you are getting error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void moveUp(int amount) 
 {
            amount = xcoord + 1;
 }
```

As per your method implementation your method call must be

> MoveUp(someIntegerValue)

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions about the `moveUp` method expecting an `int` as an argument are all valid - but I have noticed also that what you do inside these methods does not make sense - for instance you assign the new value into the `amount` which you passed in as an argument. I think what you want to do is to update the `xcoord` or the `ycoord`

With that, your code should look like this:

```
    public void moveUp(int amount) 
    {
        xcoord += (amount+ 1);
    }


    public void moveDown(int amount) 
    {           
        ycoord  -=(amount +2);
    }


    public void moveRight(int amount)
    {
       xcoord  += (amount + 1);
    }


    public void moveLeft(int amount) 
    {            
        xcoord - =(amount+1);
    }
```

And as already suggested, you call the `moveUp` method like this from your main:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point x1 = new Point();
        int someAmount = 50;
        x1.moveUp(someAmount );
        System.out.print(x1);
    }
```

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

These methods are declared wrongly!

```
    public void moveUp(int amount) 
    {
        amount = xcoord + 1;
    }


    public void moveDown(int amount) 
    {
        amount = ycoord - 2;


    }


    public void moveRight(int amount)
    {
        amount = xcoord + 1;

    }


    public void moveLeft(int amount) 
    {
        amount = xcoord - 1;


    }
```

These methods each has an `amount` parameter, I suppose you want the point to move up, down, left, right for a certain amount. To do that, you shouldn't assign `xcoord - 1` to `amount` because it does nothing practical. Also, you seem to mess up the x and y coordinates.

Instead, do this:

```
    public void moveUp(int amount) 
    {
        ycoord += amount;
    }


    public void moveDown(int amount) 
    {
        ycoord -= amount;


    }


    public void moveRight(int amount)
    {
        xcoord += amount;

    }


    public void moveLeft(int amount) 
    {
        xcoord -= amount;


    }
```

Now the methods are all correct, let's see how you can call a method properly.

As I said earlier, the `moveXXX` methods need an amount as an argument. So if you call it like this:

```
x1.moveUp();
```

it doesn't work because `moveUp` doesn't know how much it should move up. You need to give it a value. Let's say 10:

```
x1.moveUp(10);
```

Now `x1.getX()` will return 10!

Also, I suggest you overriding `toString`. This way, `println()` can actually print something meaningful:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "(" + getX() + ", " + getY() + ")"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public void moveUp(int amount) 
        {
            amount = xcoord + 1;
        }
remember this method is asking an int value as its argument value.
So you need to give a particular int value.
like  :
x1.moveUp(500);